# java cannot find symbol method

Tags: java

1st

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MyFile {

public String[] readFiles(String FileName){
        String[] names = new String[]{};
        String line = null;
        try{
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(FileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        for(int i = 0;(line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null;i++) {
                    names[i] = line;
                }   


        bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return names;
}

public static void write(String FileName,String[] names){
    try{
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(FileName);

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        for(int i = 0; i<names.length ; i++)
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(names[i]);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedWriter.close();
        }

    catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public MyFile(){System.out.println("");}
}
```

2nd

```
public class Book{
public void displayAll(){
String[] bookNames;
String filename = "Books.txt";
bookNames = readFiles(filename);
for(int i=0;i<bookNames.length;i++)
{
System.out.println(""+bookNames[i]);
}
}
}
```

I'm a beginner in java and I am trying to create a program that will save and read books' name from a txt file.
but i get this error

```
Book.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol: method readFiles(java.lang.String)
location:class com.acme.Book
     bookNames = readFiles(filename);
                 ^
```

i did tried to search but i just couldn't find any answer... and by the way not all of the code is written by me..

updated the mistkae (`readFiles`)

Comment: `readFile` is not `readFiles` ... or vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

```
bookNames = readFile(filename);
```

You don't have `readFile()` method you have `readFiles()`  method. **s** is missing in the end.

That should be

```
bookNames = readFiles(filename);
```

Comment: my mistake. but even after i change `readFile()` to `readFiles()`, i still having the same error(cannot find symbol).

Comment: Can you please update your post with current error and code ?

Comment: i'm sorry... and i just did. thanks in adv

Answer (score 0):

The method name is a plural

`readFiles`

not

`readFile`

Answer (score 0):

You got

```
public String[] readFiles(String FileName){}
```

But you are calling

```
bookNames = readFile(filename); // readFile() ? should be readFiles()
```

You can do one of following to solve this

Change

```
bookNames = readFile(filename);
```

in to

```
bookNames = readFiles(filename);
```

Or

Change

```
 public String[] readFiles(String FileName){}
```

in to

```
 public String[] readFile(String FileName){}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. as everyone meantion, you defined method `readFiles` and you are calling method `readFile`
2. Worth to meantion as wel, your method `readFiles` is defined in class `MyFile` while you are trying to access it from class `Book` which is impossible unless `Book` is inner class of `MyFile` (but this will be bad design).